# Solve $\mathbb{Q}$[X] /$\mathbb{Q}$[X]($X^3$+$X$) $\cong$ $\mathbb{Q}$ x $\mathbb{Q}$[X]/($X^2$ $+$ $1$)

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, algebraic-groups

I need to solve the following 2 questions:

1)  $\mathbb{Q}$$[X]$/$\mathbb{Q}$$[X]$($X^3$+$X$) $\cong$ $\mathbb{Q}$ x $\mathbb{Q}$$[X]$/($X^2$ $+$ $1$)

2)  $\mathbb{R}$$[X]$/$\mathbb{R}$$[X]$($X^4$$-$$1$) $\cong$ $\mathbb{R}$ x $\mathbb{R}$ x $\mathbb{C}$

For the second questions I tried the following:

($X^4$$-$$1$) = ($X$$+$$1$)($X$$-$$1$)($X^2$$+$$1$) gives $\cong$ $\mathbb{R}$ x $\mathbb{R}$ x $\mathbb{C}$.

Any help would be grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the first, $x^3+x=x(x^2+1)$.

Comment: The theorem you want to use is called the Chinese Remainder Theorem :)

Comment: I know I have to try that, but I could not figure out how to find the right answer.

Comment: For example, I do not know if my (partial)answer of question 2 is the right answer

Comment: So for your second question, the CRT says that:
$$\mathbb{R}[X]/(X+1)(X-1)(X^2+1)\cong \mathbb{R}[X]/(X+1)\times\mathbb{R}[X]/(X-1)\times \mathbb{R}[X]/(X^2+1)$$
Now you want to show that 

$$\mathbb{R}[X]/(X+1)\cong \mathbb{R}$$

$$\mathbb{R}[X]/(X-1)\cong \mathbb{R}$$

$$\mathbb{R}[X]/(X^2+1)\cong \mathbb{C}$$

Comment: If you really don't know what $\Bbb RX]/(X-1)$ is then read again about [quotient rings of polynomial rings](http://sites.millersville.edu/bikenaga/abstract-algebra-1/quotient-rings-of-polynomial-rings/quotient-rings-of-polynomial-rings.html).

Comment: Thankyou, this helps me a lot

Comment: I read the paper and tried to solve it, but I still cant figure it out... Is there anyway you could expand your answer?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).